# Firebase Firestore error on build : Call to constructor of 'firebase::firestore::util::FormatArg' is ambiguous

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm using React Native Firebase for my React Native project. Recently I updated my RNFirebase and Pods, and now this error shows up when I try to build the app.

It will go away if I remove Firestore from my Podfile.

[image]

Here is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'creativuse' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for creativuse

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'creativuseTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I can't seem to find anything about this error anywhere. Any thoughts?

**Environment**

- Application Target Platform: iOS
- Development Operating System: macOS High Sierra
- Build Tools: Xcode 9.2
- React Native version: 0.55.3
- RNFirebase Version: 4.2.0
- Firebase Module: Firestore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the latest version of 'Firebase/Firestore' (v**5.2.0**) is NOT OK

Use an old version of Firestore is a workaround

Edit Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '5.1.0'
```

Run again

```
pod update
```

This works for me!

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Wasted hours on this. Out of curiosity, when can i see list of releases for all these firebase libraries? can't figure it out on their website.

Comment: NP. You and I met the same problem at the same time. HAHA